# Autofac - Resolving Generic Interface

Tags: generics, asp.net-core, autofac

I am having an issue resolving a type implementing a generic interface. The following are the event class, generic interface, and class implementing the generic interface.

```
public class ExampleEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    public ExampleEvent()
    {
        DateTimeEventOccurred = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime DateTimeEventOccurred { get; private set; }
}

public interface IHandle<T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T args);
}

public class ExampleEventHandler : IHandle<ExampleEvent>
{
    public ExampleEventHandler()
    {
    }

    public void Handle(ExampleEvent args)
    {
        //Handle Event
    }
}
```

Here is my Autofac configuration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(assembly)).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandle<>));
        builder.Populate(services);
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(builder.Build());
```

Finally, here is the class containing the container and method responsible for raising events:

public class DomainEventHandler
    {
        public ILifetimeScope _container { get; set; }

```
    public DomainEventHandler(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        foreach (var handler in _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandle<T>>>())
        {
            handler.Handle(args);
        }
    }
}
```

When the Resolve method is called, the result is an empty collection. However, if I replace the generic with a concrete type, the container will successfully resolve and provide an instance of ExampleEventHandler. Using TryResolve with the generic results in a value of true, while outputting an empty instance.

When first implementing this pattern, I started off using StructureMap and ran into the same issue, so I assume there is something silly I am doing in both cases. I am able to successfully use the container in many other scenarios not utilizing generics.

Update:

The issue seems to be associated with a type comparison of some sort. When calling all of my queued up domain events in my savechanges method, the dependency will resolve if I pass a new instance of a domain event.

For example, this will succeed:

```
foreach (var domainEvent in entity.DeferredEvents.ToArray())
                {
                    _handler.Raise(new EstimateAuditEvent(1,1, DateTime.Now));
                }
```

Whereas this will fail:

```
foreach (var domainEvent in entity.DeferredEvents.ToArray())
                {
                    _handler.Raise(domainEvent);
                }
```

my collection on my entity is as follows:

```
public List<IDomainEvent> DeferredEvents { get; set; }
```

I am still not certain how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by your call to `_handler.Raise`. As you said the `DeferredEvents` are stored in a `List<IDomainEvent>`. This causes your failing code to look like this:

```
foreach (var domainEvent in entity.DeferredEvents.ToArray())
{
    _handler.Raise<IDomainEvent>(domainEvent);
}
```

Hence, your `Raise` method for this call will look like this:

```
public void Raise<IDomainEvent>(IDomainEvent args) where T : IDomainEvent
{
    foreach (var handler in _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandle<IDomainEvent>>>())
    {
        handler.Handle(args);
    }
}
```

Looking at your registrations there is no event handler which implements the `IHandle<IDomainEvent>` interface. There is only one implementing the `IHandle<ExampleEvent>` interface. So consequently your call to resolve `IEnumerable<IHandle<IDomainEvent>>` will yield no result.

#### Update

> So in that case would there be no way to loop through a collection of an Interface or base class? Under the above assumptions Autofac will resolve an instance based upon the interface or base class instead of the derived type, but I have seen this same approach taken in many Domain Events examples.

Autofac resolves based on the registration. In your example the `ExampleEventHandler` implements `IHandle<ExampleEvent>` and is registered as `IHandle<ExampleEvent>`, so an instance of `ExampleEventHandler` won't be returned if you resolve `IEnumerable<IHandle<IDomainEvent>>`.

However, I don't think that the registration is wrong, I think the error lies in the way the `Raise` method is called. The `Raise` method has a generic type parameter `T` which is not used (at least not in your example). In your example the `Raise` method effectively looks like this:

```
public void Raise(IDomainEvent args)
{
    foreach (var handler in _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandle<IDomainEvent>>>())
    {
        handler.Handle(args);
    }
}
```

You'll have to update your code so that the derived types of `IDomainEvent` are used for `T`, so that Autofac can find the correct handlers:

```
_handler.Raise<ExampleEvent>(domainEvent);
```

Alternatively, you could change all your handlers to implement `IHandle<IDomainEvent>>` and then simply do nothing if the type of the event does not match the expected type:

```
public class ExampleEventHandler : IHandle<IDomainEvent>
{
    public ExampleEventHandler()
    {
    }

    public void Handle(IDomainEvent args)
    {
        if (!(args is ExampleEvent))
            return;

        //Handle Event
    }
}
```

Comment: So in that case would there be no way to loop through a collection of an Interface or base class? Under the above assumptions Autofac will resolve an instance based upon the interface or base class instead of the derived type, but I have seen this same approach taken in many Domain Events examples.